# Request object sent to django form ok when sent via GET but empty when sent via POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to send the request user to a Django form, the thing is, when I sent the object trough GET metho, the Django form receives it fine, but when I do it trough POST method, the request object it's always empty, here's the code :

***************Views.py

```
class CreateRec(BaseView):

    template_name = 'test/rec.html'


    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        rec_form = RecForm(req_ses = request)
        return render(request, self.template_name,{
            'rec_form': rec_form, 'f_new': True,
        })

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        user_rec = User.objects.get(username = request)
        profile = profile_models.RecProfile.objects.get(cnxuser = user_rec)
        form = RecForm(request.POST, request.FILES, req_ses = request)
        return render(request, self.template_name,{
            'rec_form': rec_form, 'f_new': True,
        })
```

***********The fragment of the Form.py file:

```
class RecForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, req_ses = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.req_ses = kwargs.pop('req_ses', None)
        user_rec = User.objects.get(username = req_ses.user)
        profile = profile_models.RecProfile.objects.get(cnxuser = user_rec)
```

Via GET, req_ses has the object , via POST It's says req_ses it's None.....any idea why ??, I tried to send the user_rec object too but got the same result....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the `req_ses` argument and all that extra work you do to find the `request.user`, since [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) objects have the `user` attribute.

Here is your code, with some simplifications that will *hopefully* fix the problem:

forms.py:

```
class RecForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        instance = profile_models.RecProfile.objects.get(cnxuser=user) 
        super(RecForm, self).__init__(*args, instance=instance, **kwargs)
```

views.py:

```
class CreateRec(BaseView):
    template_name = 'test/rec.html' 

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        rec_form = RecForm(user=request.user)
        return render(request, self.template_name,{
            'rec_form': rec_form, 'f_new': True,
        })

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = RecForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
        return render(request, self.template_name,{
            'rec_form': rec_form, 'f_new': True,
        })
```

### Update

```
class RecForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        print('args: {}'.format(args))
        print('kwargs: {}'.format(kwargs))
        print('user: {}'.format(user))
        instance = profile_models.RecProfile.objects.get(cnxuser=user) 
        super(RecForm, self).__init__(*args, instance=instance, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind response, I tried your code but got the same problem, in this case 'user' it's ok inside the form when I use GET, but still empty when I use POST, it's a really weird problem, don't know why it's empty only when its sent via POST...

Comment: @jsanchezs it might be due to the position you have your form arguments in.  For example your form might be thinking `request.FILES`  is actually your user object.  Anyways, can you add print statements like I did in my update, and show me the results?

Comment: The print sintax shows error: 'Invalid' but if I use a trace args shows error saying "Form has no attribute errors", kwargs got an instance of Rec ans user is empty

Comment: sorry, `f-strings` were introduced in python 3.4 (i think).  Are you using an earlier version?

Comment: Nope, 3.5.2 inside a virtual environment

Comment: my bad, it's actually 3.6

Comment: Ok, it throws this :   args: ()  //
kwargs: {'instance': <Rec: 0. aplica con el ajuste>}  //
user: None